# Android Image Share to Another App Where is problem?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, uri, share

Im doing an app and i want to share photo just i saved to phone to another apps like instagram twitter.Im not able to do it and i cant see where the mistake is.Here is my code

```
`private fun getScreenshot(currentPage: Int){
        QuickShot.of(requireActivity().findViewById<ConstraintLayout(currentPage))
            .setResultListener(this)
            .enableLogging()
            .setFilename("screen")
            .setPath("Spotibud")
            .toJPG()
            .save()
    }

    override fun onQuickShotSuccess(path: String?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onQuickShotSuccess: $path")
        shareOnInstagram(path!!)
    }

    override fun onQuickShotFailed(path: String?, errorMsg: String?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onQuickShotFailed: $errorMsg")
    }
    private fun shareOnInstagram(path: String){
     
        val stickerAssetUri: Uri = Uri.parse(path)
        val intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,stickerAssetUri)
            type = "image/*"
        }
        startActivity(intent)

    }`
```

and my log when app saves image

```
2021-02-18 17:28:08.750 16355-16355/com.example.contestifyfirsttry D/Home Fragment: onQuickShotSuccess: /Pictures/Spotibud/screen.jpg
```

also is there any code how i can see error.try catch not worked

Comment: `/Pictures/Spotibud/screen.jpg` That is not a valid full path. It cannot exist to begin with. `Pictures/Spotibud/screen.jpg` could be a valid relative path though.

Comment: Use the File class to check if the used path exists before you try to forward it. Use File.exists().

Comment: @blackapps thats it!! thank you so much im looking for 2 days to solve this. it was wrong path you make me so happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i found the solution this isnt best practice but im sure it makes you to see what you should do

```
private fun shareOnInstagram(path: String){

    var file : File = File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Spotibud/screen.jpg")
    if (file.exists()){
        Log.d(TAG, "shareOnInstagram: file exists")
        val stickerAssetUri: Uri = Uri.fromFile(file)
        val sourceApplication = "com.example.contestifyfirsttry"

        val intent = Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY")
        intent.putExtra("source_application", sourceApplication)

        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.putExtra("interactive_asset_uri", stickerAssetUri)
        intent.putExtra("top_background_color", "#33FF33")
        intent.putExtra("bottom_background_color", "#FF00FF")
        val activity: Activity? = activity
        activity!!.grantUriPermission(
            "com.instagram.android", stickerAssetUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        )
        if (activity!!.packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, 0) != null) {
            activity!!.startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
        }
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "shareOnInstagram: file dont exists")
    }
}
```